# Identify and eliminate extraneous/noise values from a data series in R

Tags: r, noise

I have a dataframe with date, temperature and time. This dataframe can have thousands of lines, depending on the number of temperature measurements. Sometimes there are measurement errors and one or more wrong values appear in the dataframe. How can I eliminate lines with wrong temperatures automatically, in R?

Here is an example:

```
              date  temp   time
    1   2021-09-01    14 04:59:27
    2   2021-09-01    15 04:59:28
    3   2021-09-01    15 04:59:30
    4   2021-09-01    14 04:59:30
    5   2021-09-01    14 04:59:32
    6   2021-09-01    10 04:59:32
    7   2021-09-01    14 04:59:33
    8   2021-09-01    14 04:59:35
    9   2021-09-01    15 04:59:35
    10  2021-09-01    14 04:59:36
    11  2021-09-01    15 04:59:37
    12  2021-09-01     6 04:59:38
    13  2021-09-01     6 04:59:39
    14  2021-09-01     6 04:59:41
    15  2021-09-01    14 04:59:41
    16  2021-09-01    15 04:59:42
    17  2021-09-01    15 04:59:44
    18  2021-09-01    14 04:59:44
    19  2021-09-01    15 04:59:45
    20  2021-09-01    15 04:59:45
    21  2021-09-01    15 04:59:45

(...)
```

Of course row 6, 12,13,14 are not correct because this variation in seconds is impossible, and I want to remove them.

Emphasizing: I need an automatic way to identify and later eliminate these rows, as I may have other similar cases in the thousands of rows

Comment: Why row 6, 12, 13, and 14 are wrong? How to determine that some rows are wrong?

Comment: I presume you could take a running average over some period (e.g. with `slider::slide_index()`) and filter out values that are some threshold out of range, based on your domain knowledge of what kind of changes are normal and what are probably erroneous.

Comment: Are wrong because it is impossible the temperature decrease  and increase 8 degrees in 5 seconds, or in the same second have 2 different values.

Comment: Additionally, by using running average, my problem is how to define the threshold because I can have temperatures arround 6, for example in the final of the day, but in this example running average near 6 means that I have wrong values...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using a bunch of libraries for convenience.

First, I convert the date + time to a combined timestamp in POSIXct date-time format. Then I take a 30 second rolling average of temperature and calculate each point's variance from that. (Note, it can be difficult to come up with the right "noise" filter without some domain knowledge; if there were many more erroneous readings, eventually they would look like the "right" ones here.) Finally, I graph those and show how in this case a threshold of +/- 3 degrees distinguishes the noisy values from the correct once.

```
library(dplyr); library(lubridate); library(slider); library(ggplot2)
df1 %>%
  mutate(timestamp = lubridate::mdy_hms(paste(date, time))) %>% 
  mutate(rolling_avg = slider::slide_index_dbl(temp, timestamp, mean, 
                                               .before = 30)) %>%
  mutate(variance = temp - rolling_avg) %>%
  ggplot(aes(timestamp, temp)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = rolling_avg), lty = "dashed") +
  geom_point(aes(color = abs(variance) > 3))
```

[image]